# Suppose $G$ is a non-abelian group and $a\in G$. Prove that if $C(a)=\left \langle a\right \rangle$ then $a\notin Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a non-abelian group and $a \in G$. Prove that if $C(a) =\left \langle a \right \rangle$ then $a \notin Z(G)$. We know that
$C(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$ in $G$ and $Z(G)$ is the center of the group $G$.

Comment: What do you know about $C(b)$ for $b\in Z(G)$?

Answer (score 3):

If $a\in Z(G)$, then $G=C(a)$.  By assumption, $G$ is nonabelian, so in particular $G=C(a)$ is not cyclic.